# Create Stored procedure with if else

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Create a table with five columns A, B, C, D and E with varchar(100) as their data types. Table Name will be My_table
Write a stored procedure named Update_Records which will accept 1 parameter.

```
@col_name varchar(100)
```

If I pass any column name to this procedure, it will check if the column is already present in the table. If present it will print ‘Column already exists’. If not present, you will alter My_table and add that column. Output will be: ‘Table Altered’

For example if I call stored procedure as

```
Exec Update_Records ‘B’
```

Output will be:

```
Column already exists.

Exec Update_Records ‘N’
```

Output will be:

```
Table Altered
```

Code

```
ALTER PROC Update_records (@col_name VARCHAR(100))
AS
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   my_table)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'already exists'
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Table Altered'
        END

      UPDATE my_Table
      SET    @col_name = @col_name
  END
```

Comment: alter proc Update_Records (@col_name varchar(100))
as
begin
If exists (select * from my_table)
begin
print 'already exists'
end
else
begin
print 'Table Altered'
end
update my_Table
set @col_name=@col_name
end

Comment: This looks like an interview question.

Answer (score 0):

- You are checking for records exists in the table not column exists
- You need `Alter` statement to add column not `Update` statement

something like this

```
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.my_table', @col_name) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Column already exists'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
     SET @col_name = QUOTENAME(@col_name)
     EXEC ('Alter Table my_table ADD '+@col_name+' varchar(100)')
     PRINT 'Table Altered'
END
```

Comment: I can't imagine what the DBA would say about this. And ANSI text too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Even to me its looks like a weird request. In real world I don't see many adding column on the fly. Just showing there is a way to do it..

Comment: The ugly part it that if this is indeed an interview question ... image what the production code looks like. If it isn't, same^2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could be also a test in a university.